# Can I do cardio exercises after an appendicitis operation?

Tags: running, cardio, bicycling

I got operated on 3rd of January this year (it was an appendicitis operation). The surgery was open. Now its been more than 3 months and I have putted on a lot of weights.
I just wanted to do cardio exercises like cycling or running on a treadmill.

Now the question is, whether should I go ahead with cardio like cycling or wait some more time. If I can continue what should be the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Have you talked to your surgeon about this plan?

Comment: No I haven't,but its been 15 weeks.

Comment: Although it's been 15 weeks, and you and I both know that it may be safe to start on some sort of an exercise program.  I would strongly suggest for you to give him a call to make sure that you got an "OK" to do so.  If anything, he can at least recommend you to see a trainer or a physical therapist, etc.  Good luck!

Comment: There shouldn't be a real reason to see a PT with an appendectomy. You need to clear exercise with your doctor (should only take a phone call and you will probably only talk to a nurse/mid level). If you start before your wound has completely healed it can cause major issues. The problem with looking up average recovery times from specific surgeries is that everyone recovers differently.

Comment: This may be too individualized to be meaningful to others. Erring on the side of caution, I wouldn't want someone else to take information from here that might cause them harm so I'm going to close it.